How to Address URL Manipulation Vulnerabilities in Spring Boot Application Exporting JSON Data?
I'm developing a Spring Boot application where I have an endpoint /EventDataExport/ that accepts JSON data. I'm concerned about URL manipulation vulnerabilities in my code.
Here's a summarized snippet of my code:
`@RequestMapping(value = "/dataexport/")
public ResponseEntity events(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody JsonNode eventInfo)
throws DiagnosticsException, IOException, ParseException {
StringBuilder resultFilePathBuilder = createResultFilePathBuilder(sourceUuId, evtQueryUrlParamMap);
ResponseEntity<?> evtResponse = fileGeneration(evtMap, evtQueryMap, params);

}
private void fillEventQueryUrlMap(JsonNode evtReqObj, Map<String, String> evtQueryMap,
Map<String, String> evtQueryUrlMap) {
}`
Problem:
I'm concerned about the potential for URL manipulation vulnerabilities in my exportEvents method. The code seems to use user-controllable input to specify a URL, which could lead to attackers accessing unintended files or malicious websites.
Solution Attempt:
I've read about URL manipulation vulnerabilities and understand the importance of proper input validation. However, I'm unsure about the best practices to implement in my Spring Boot application to mitigate these vulnerabilities.
Desired Solution:
I'm seeking guidance oyour textn how to properly validate and sanitize user inputs to prevent URL manipulation vulnerabilities in my Spring Boot application. Additionally, I'm specifically concerned about the line:
Json Node is used to create a map with gettext and later used for File response as well.
 File response = getEvents(evtQueryMap, resultFilePathBuilder);
This call to getEvents seems to use evtQueryMap sensitive computation, which raises further concerns about potential vulnerabilities. Any advice or code examples demonstrating secure practices for handling user-controlled URLs and preventing URL manipulation vulnerabilities would be greatly appreciated.
